# error while pushing an app to heroku

Tags: heroku, pom.xml

I get an error while pushing my app from eclipse to heroku.

it says 
 javac: invalid target release 1.7

how to rectify it

this is my pom.xml plugin

```
                            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```